# how to create dependent dropdown list in CRUD Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am a beginner and trying to create CRUD Django Application where I want to keep the below fields.

```
Company Name
DOB 
Date and time
State (should be dependency between State and City)
City (should be dependency between State and City)
```

Please help me for complete code

For example i give input as:

```
company name : ABC
DOB Date and time : 2022-01-01 08:12:00
State : Karnataka(if I select State "Karnataka" then related city of Karnataka has to be showed in dropdown)
City : Bangalore, Mysore
```

if I click on edit button entire field's value has to be show

#### form design has to horizontal (for Example)

```
company name DOB , Date and time
State ,  City
```

#### Not like this (for Example)

```
company name DOB 
Date and time
State
City
```

Comment: Please, describe exactly your problem, and format your code

Comment: Normally form in django viewed vertically. Can i make form as Horizontally for example.. label1 label2

Answer (score 1):

### I created CRUD mini project with Dependent Dropdown

Repo link [here](https://github.com/Mahammadhusain/CRUD-mini-project-with-Dependent-Dropdown.git)

#### Browser Output

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! But I need complete crud operation including Date & Time Field and Company name field. if it possible please create mini project including field which were mentioned. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answer is updated check it

Comment: Repo link added

Comment: Can you please share me the code

Comment: Link added check in answer

Comment: Can you please add one more drop down as you had shown in CRUD mini project with Dependent Dropdown. Thanks in advance

Comment: plz check as the right answer ✅

Comment: one more dropdown field i want to add in same project. example. if select from

Comment: one more dropdown field i want to add in same project. example....Field name - fruit
if i select "Orange" then, Nagpur Orange can be selected
if i select "Apple" then,Kasmir Apple can be selected
like how did you make dropdown between state and city.

Comment: I am waiting for your reply

Comment: You can do this follow existing code

Comment: i tried a lot but not able to do it. Can you please add one more dropdown in the same project then my conception will be clear.

Comment: Sorry i am asking again, i want add one more two more fields like State and City dependency.                                                                                                                           #Should i create one more template like subcategory.html example <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
{% for i in droptwo %}
    <option value="{{i.id}}">{{i.name}}</option>
{% endfor %}

Comment: Sorry i am asking again, i want to add two more fields.....like State and City dependency.                                                                                                                           #Should i create one more template and views?

Comment: How to write two ids in jquery and ajax. i tried as below

Comment: <script>
        $('#process','#state').change(function () {
            var myurl = $('#myform').attr("data-course-url");
            var processid = $(this).val();
            var stateid = $(this).val();
            console.log('hello')    ....but not working

Comment: i was requested you to add one more dependent dropdown and i have created successful with help of your 1st dependent dropdown

Comment: now i am trying for normal Dropdown(not dependent dropdown). is it must create choice in model.py?

Comment: how make CRUD Operation of normal dropdown?